# type-problems in C

Tags: c, pointers, incompatibletypeerror

This may be a stupid question, and I see similar questions been asked, but I dont get the answers given. why does the following code produce:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node_t’ from type ‘struct node_t *’

```
node_t list_array[10];
typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node_t;

node_t* create_node(void)
{
    node_t *np;
    np->next = NULL;
    np->prev = NULL;
    np->value = rand() % 10;
    return np;
}

int main(void)
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list_array[i] = create_node();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have global array holding 10 `node_t` objects, when you're obviously going to dynamically create nodes while implementnig doubly-linked list? Wouldn't be the simple pointer to `root` node enough?

Comment: @LihO, maybe dexter wants ten different linked lists :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well, that would also explain name `list_array`. :) But I don't think that he wants to create 10 linked lists and use this array to store 10 root nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the array into an array of pointers to fix the error, since `create_node` returns a pointer:

```
node_t *list_array[10];
```

Note you're not allocating any memory in `create_node` so using `np` is illegal. Try:

```
node_t *np = malloc(sizeof *np);
```

> I want to make an array of node_t structs

In that case you could leave the node_t list_array[10] and:

- Pass `&list_array[i]` as an argument to the function
- Have the function return a `node_t` instead of a `node_t *`

Comment: I want to make an array of node_t structs. If I understand correct. The array declaration as is will set aside/define a memory space (therefore no use of malloc). The pointers next and previous will point to the memory spaces in the array, but will at the same time offer an alternative structure/way of iterating the array.

Answer (score 4):

Because one is a structure and the other is a *pointer* to the structure.

The `create_node()` function returns a *pointer* to a node (which you really should `malloc()` in that function, by the way) and you try to assign it to an actual structure in the array.

You can solve it by simply changing your declaration to:

```
node_t *list_array[10];
```

so that it's an array of pointers rather than an array of structures.

Answer (score 4):

Because `create_node()` returns a *pointer*, but `list_array[i]` is an actual *instance*. You can't assign a pointer over an instance, they're completely different.

The solution is typically to represent each node as a pointer, which requires `list_array` to be an array of pointers:

```
node_t *list_array[10];
```

Then the assigment makes sense, and the code will compile.

Note, however, that the code will not "work", since it's dereferencing a `NULL` pointer inside `create_node()`. It seems you forgot to call `malloc()`:

```
node_t* create_node(void)
{
    node_t *np;
    if((np = malloc(sizeof *np)) != NULL)
    {
        np->next = NULL;
        np->prev = NULL;
        np->value = rand() % 10;
    }
    return np;
}
```

Comment: `node_t *np;` The value of np is indeterminate, here. How can you determine that an indeterminate value is a null pointer? There's no such thing as a NULL pointer, because NULL isn't an lvalue. Don't confuse the term "null pointer" with the value that NULL represents, which happens to be just one member of the set of null pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic "pointer vs. instance" confusion. Even more serious than your warning is:

```
node_t *np;
np->next = NULL;
```

which will compile, and then segfault.

The confusion arises because of a misunderstanding of what a pointer is. When compiled, a pointer is just a single number, like 140734799803888. This number is used *just to locate* the physical chunk of data. It's a memory *address*.

Pointers vs. instances are confusing, and one of the first conceptual challenges you encounter in programming. So here's an analogy:

If you've ever used a GPS, it will tell you *where* you are (pointer) but not *what* you are (data). Pointers work the same way. If someone wants to shake your hand, they wouldn't shake GPS coordinates (pointer)! They'd use the GPS coordinates to locate you, then physically visit you (data) and shake your hand. That's how pointers work.

So in your code above, you declare a pointer `np`, but don't give it any location to keep track of. Then, you ask "use the number in `np` to locate my data" (but you haven't set a number for `np`!) In particular, `np->next` asks to use the location `np + someOffset` (which is undefined!) to find your physical data (which is nowhere), and change it.

That's why you get a seg fault.

Comment: Thank you, jeremy. I am interested in a deeper understanding of pointers. Sorry for keep on asking, but I now removed the declaration of next pointers pointing to NULL. However, I kept the assignment of np->value. I still get the same error, but what I am struggling with (as well as what you tell me) is that by saying node_t *np I have declared a memory position that is supposed to point to a node_t...but not actually created one? how would I create that the pointer would point to (without using malloc)?

Comment: If you wish to get around memory allocation, you can return a node_t directly. Replacing every "node_t*" with "node_t" would work. Instead of passing locations (aka pointers), you would be passing the ENTIRE CONTENTS of the structure around. It doesn't make sense with a linked list, but it's possible if you can't use malloc().

Comment: sorry, I should also say that your node_t struct declaration wouldn't change; you'd still use pointers as in "struct node* next" so you can use them to "refer to" (aka locate) the actual data that's "next".

Answer (score 0):

`node_t list_array[10]` should be `node_t *list_array[10]`
You have also, not `malloc`ed your `node_t *np`

`node_t *np = malloc(sizeof(node_t));`

Comment: I think there was much help to get from this. I have to say that the explanation of jeremy was very good. I also believed that someone suggested to give the memory address of each array-position to a function with a pointer parameter. This pointer would then allow me to manipulate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

For this program, I see no point to using dynamic storage duration (malloc). I would dispose of create_node in favour of memcpy, if you wish to keep all of your objects in static storage duration. For example,

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node_t;

int main(void) {
    node_t list_array[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (list_array) / sizeof (*list_array); i++) {
        memcpy(list_array + i,
               &(node_t){ .value = rand() % 10,
                          .next = NULL,
                          .prev = NULL },
               sizeof (*list_array));
    }
    return 0;
}
```